# Trigger with callout not updating a field on Case object

Tags: apex, trigger, callout, field-update, update

I have a future callout which is triggered after case creation/update.
The callout sends a request to my backend to create a resource there, then, it returns the resource ID, and it should ideally add this custom resource ID to the Case object where the trigger was initiated from.

The problem is that this custom resource ID field is not being updated. The external resource is being created and the response code for the request is 201, so that part is working. It's only on Salesforce that the record is not updating to reflect the custom ID.

This is my trigger

```
trigger CreateExternalResource on Case (after insert, after update) {
    
    for(Case c : Trigger.new){
        if (c.Create_External_Resource__c == true && c.External_Resource_ID__c == null){
            String storyTitle = c.Subject;
            String storyDescription = c.Description;
            Integer projectId = ExternalResourceUtilities.determineProjectId(c.Project__c);
            ExternalProject project = new ExternalProject(projectId);
            ExternalResource story = new ExternalResource(storyTitle, project, storyDescription);
            String serializedStory = JSON.serialize(story, true);
            if(!System.isFuture()){
                ExternalResourceCreator.createStory(c.id, serializedStory);
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

The createStory method from ExternalResourceCreator

```
@future(callout=true)
    public static void createStory(ID caseId, String serializedStory){
       
        Case caseToUpdate = [SELECT Subject, Description, External_Resource_ID__c FROM Case where id = :caseId];

        
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        String authToken = 'myToken';
        PageReference ref = new PageReference('https://myendpoint.com/api/Stories?');
        ref.getParameters().putAll(new Map<String, String> {
            'format' => 'json',
            'access_token' => authToken
        });
        req.setEndpoint(ref.getUrl());
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', '4096');
        req.setBody(serializedStory);
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        
        if(res.getStatusCode() != 201){
            caseToUpdate.Project__c = null;
            caseToUpdate.Create_External_Resource__c = false;
            caseToUpdate.External_Resource_ID__c = null;
        } else{
            caseToUpdate.Create_External_Resource__c = true;
            Integer storyId = ExternalResourceUtilities.getStoryId(res.getBody());
            caseToUpdate.External_Resource_ID__c = storyId;
        }
         
        update caseToUpdate;
    }
```

getStoryId Method

```
public static Integer getStoryId(String responseBody){
        Integer storyId = 0;
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(responseBody);
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && 
                (parser.getText() == 'Id')) {
                
                parser.nextToken();

                if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT){
                    return storyId = parser.getIntegerValue();
                } else {
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }
        
        return storyId;
    }
```

So why is the `External_Resource_ID__c` not getting updated?

Comment: Do you know that the `getStoryId` method is working? Assuming your `Id` is not buried too deep in the `JSON` response, it'd probably be easier to define a `Story` class and deserialize your response into that. Have you tried adding a debug log or just running this code in execute anon?

Comment: I have 100% code coverage, the getStoryId() is passing the tests, but I'll double check it. Could it be something else?

Comment: I just verified through debugging that the story ID returned from getStoryId is correct.

Also, it is accesing the else block in the createStory method.

So it's just not actually updating the record

Comment: is there a possibility that after the Case is updated, that a before save Flow or trigger is resetting the storyId back to null?

Comment: No, its a custom field I created specifically for this task and its a testing sandbox, so there's nothing else accessing the case.

My guess is that the `ID` being passed to createStory is not actually fetching any records so there's nothing to update.

Comment: There are no validation for the fields. Wrote a unit test to check whether the record was reflecting the updated values and it failed

Comment: remove the `@future` and just call that method from exec anon. Just the serialized case + the case id. There'll be an exception and you should catch it.